# How to solve ERROR Mwe2Launcher: Couldn't find EClass for name

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, xtext, eclipse-emf-ecore, xpand

I created a Xpand generator. In its src/ folder I've defined my model My.nn a template and a workflow.

This is how my workflow.mwe2 file looks like:

```
module workflow.NeuralNetworksGenerator

import org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.*

var targetDir = "src-gen"
var fileEncoding = "Cp1252"
var modelPath = "src/model"

Workflow {
    component = org.eclipse.xtext.mwe.Reader {
        // lookup all resources on the classpath
        //useJavaClassPath = true

        // or define search scope explicitly
        path = modelPath

        // this class will be generated by the xtext generator 
        register = org.xtext.example.neuralnetworks.NeuralNetworksStandaloneSetup {}
        load = {
            slot = "systems"
            type = "System"
        }
    }

    component = org.eclipse.xpand2.Generator {
        expand = "templates::Template::main FOREACH systems"
        outlet = {
            path = targetDir
        }
        fileEncoding = fileEncoding
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to run this workflow.mwe2 file as MWE2 Workflow, I get the following errors:

```
0    INFO  AbstractExpressionsUsingWorkflowComponent - No meta models configured, using JavaBeans as default.
75   ERROR Mwe2Launcher       - Problems running workflow workflow.NeuralNetworksGenerator: Couldn't find EClass for name 'System'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problems running workflow workflow.NeuralNetworksGenerator: Couldn't find EClass for name 'System'.
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:35)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowInterruptedException: Couldn't find EClass for name 'System'.
    at org.eclipse.xtext.mwe.SlotEntry.findEClasses(SlotEntry.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.mwe.SlotEntry.put(SlotEntry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.mwe.AbstractReader.addModelElementsToContext(AbstractReader.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.mwe.Reader.invokeInternal(Reader.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:97)
    ... 5 more
```

The example that I used to create my particularized workflow mwe2 file is taken from the Xpand reference manual.

This is the list of plug-in dependencies from the MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: my.neuralnetworks.generator.project
Bundle-SymbolicName: my.neuralnetworks.generator.project; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.5.0",
 org.eclipse.xtend.profiler;resolution:=optional,
 org.apache.commons.logging,
 org.apache.log4j;resolution:=optional,
 com.ibm.icu;bundle-version="4.0.1",
 org.antlr.runtime;bundle-version="3.0.0",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.5.0",
 org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils;bundle-version="0.7.0",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi;bundle-version="2.5.0",
 org.eclipse.jface.text;bundle-version="3.5.0",
 org.eclipse.xpand;bundle-version="0.7.0",
 org.eclipse.xtend;bundle-version="0.7.0",
 org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf;bundle-version="0.7.0",
 org.eclipse.xtend.backend;bundle-version="1.0.0";resolution:=optional,
 org.eclipse.xtend.middleend.xpand;bundle-version="1.0.0";resolution:=optional,
 org.eclipse.xtend.middleend.xtend;bundle-version="1.0.0";resolution:=optional,
 neuralnetworks;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.xtext.example.neuralnetworks;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.source;bundle-version="2.7.0",
 org.eclipse.jface.text.source;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.antlr.runtime.source;bundle-version="3.2.0",
 org.antlr.runtime_3.1.b1;bundle-version="3.1.0",
 com.ibm.icu.source;bundle-version="4.4.2",
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.source;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch;bundle-version="2.2.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
Import-Package: nn
```

The *neuralnetworks* plug-in refers to my gmf project for my graphical editor where the metamodel is found and the *org.xtext.example.neuralnetworks* is the one corresponding to my text editor.

The ecore file corresponding to the emf file does have the EClass System in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your dsl look like? Does it contain a EClass named System?
Update: Just saw you do not have a Xtext based metamodel. So if you want to use the Xtext Mwe Reader Component you have to use a AbstractGenericResourceSupport and register your epackage as well as it is described in this Xtend2 example http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/xtend2-code-generators-with-non-xtext-models/

Comment: My xtext file was automatically generated because the xtext project was built from the existing Ecore model. In the xtext file there is a syntax definition for the 'System' element. From your tutorial I understand that I should modify the automatically generated files in this xtext project, i.e., the files that refer to my `StandaloneSetup` and my `RuntimeModule` classes. However, these already extend `NeuralNetworksStandaloneSetupGenerated` and `org.xtext.example.neuralnetworks.AbstractNeuralNetworksRuntimeModule`, respectively. Should I modify these?

Answer (score 0):

No, but since you use a existing metamodel and not a derived one you should add the following to the beginning of your workflow

```
bean = StandaloneSetup {
    registerGeneratedEPackage = "sample.SamplePackage"
}
```